# how does str.split() divide a string?

Tags: python, string, methods

```
line = (' 1.')
print(line.split(), len(line.split()))
```

This gives

```
['1.'] 1
```

But if I do

```
for value in line.split():
    val = value
    print(val, len(val))
```

I get

```
1. 2
```

Inspecting `val` gives me

```
val[0]
'1'
val[1]
'.'
```

I'm confused as to why ".split()" is dividing from 1 index to 2 in the second example?

Comment: `len(val)` is the size of the element (`"1."`). `len(line.split())` is the size of the list (`['1.']`)

Comment: Have you read the code to try to understand what it does?

Comment: _"I'm confused as to why ".split()" is dividing from 1 index to 2 in the second example?"_ Sorry, which part is the second example? There's only one code block here.

Comment: Try `line=" 1. 2"` and you will understand what is happening

Answer (score 2):

`split()` divides a string using spaces as separator (more than one spaces together are just un separator for this method).

see: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

You can also give the separator you want as a parameter, for example `mystr.split(",")` will use the comma as separator to split `mystr`

There is also a  second parameter that tell the method how many splits do you want to perform.

So:

```
mystr = "1 - 2 - 3 - 4"
print(mystr.split()) # split using spaces
print(mystr.split("-")) # split using "-"
print(mystr.split("-",2)) # split using "-" with 2 splits maximum
```

will produce the following output:

```
['1', '-', '2', '-', '3', '-', '4']
['1 ', ' 2 ', ' 3 ', ' 4']
['1 ', ' 2 ', ' 3 - 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

- When you do line.split() it returns a list with one element **['1.']**.
- When you iterate over the line.split (**for value in line.split()**) the variable value is each element of the list resultant by the split (**'1.'** not **['1.']**).
- Then you run **len** in the string, wich has 2 elements (the **"1"** and the **"."**).